# jQuery fileListe without change function

Tags: jquery, file, upload, filelist

At the beginning i have a question about this site. Is it really free?

Now my question:
i try to get some files from an multiple input-file tag.

I saw some tutorials, they show how it is realizable. There 's always the same part of script:

```
selectorof_input.change(function(){
files = event.target.files.........});
```

Now I need another way. I want to get the files without a change function, like:

```
var files = jQuery("input").files;
```

but this doesn't work.

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/b30kte9p/1/

thanks for help

Comment: Yes, the site is free. As long as you're asking good questions and/or provide good answers to other people's questions. Otherwise, the mods will make you pay. ;) JK, Stack Overflow is completely free, as it's funded by advertising.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the input element to have access to its files property, remember the jQuery object is a wrapper for any nodes selected.

```
var files = jQuery("input").get(0).files; // ".get(0)" gets the first selected node
```

Comment: i had try it.
it likes :

    <input type="file" name="upload" id="test" />
     function test(wert){
      var files = jQuery(wert).get(0).file;
    }
    
    test("#test");

it's only a part of the script.

i get an Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined 

see the full code:
http://jsfiddle.net/b30kte9p/2/

Comment: its `.files` with an s

Comment: i can't belive it. I feel sooooo shame. I tried this version since 3 hours. And the Probmlem was ONE letter... unbelivebel